# what is the difference between type coercion using Boolean constructor function and inside if

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

Please refer to jsfiddle here , https://jsfiddle.net/reuk08ob/
html:
`<div id="abc"></div>`
javascript :

```
if(null==false){
  document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="hello, null == true coerced";
}else if(Boolean(null)==false ){
  document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="hello, boolean constructor coercion worked! previous one did not,strange, both should do the same, shouldn't they?";
}
```

am I missing something ? shouldn't Boolean constructor do type coercion same as that done implicitly in if statement?

Answer (score 3):

`Boolean` doesn't do type coercion, it does type *conversion*, meaning that the typecasting is explicit rather than implicit.

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), Boolean works like so: "If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false."

In addition, "Do not confuse the primitive Boolean values true and false with the true and false values of the Boolean object.". In other words, the Boolean constructor returns a Boolean object, and the Boolean object has a value that is determined by the above-stated rule.