# What does open={Boolean(anchor)} mean for a MUI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Working with some legacy code where a MUI menu has been defined within a React component written with TypeScript as below:

```
interface Props {
anchor: HTMLButtonElement | null;
}
...
<Menu
  id="order-menu"
  anchorEl={anchor}
  open={Boolean(anchor)}
  onClose={onClose}
>
...
</Menu>
```

Not sure if I understand the meaning or purpose of the syntax `open={Boolean(anchor)}`. It would be kind if anyone can explain a bit.

Comment: It means the prop `open` should be set to the value of `anchor`, coerced to a `Boolean`. In this case, true if `anchor` is set, false if `null`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: you could have put your comment as an answer since you answered it first :D.

Comment: It's a duplicate question, I'm trying to find the duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between type coercion using Boolean constructor function and inside if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645597/what-is-the-difference-between-type-coercion-using-boolean-constructor-function)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, not really. My question was more about understanding the syntax first and then the meaning of it. The link you sent perhaps is a part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Boolean(...)` returns a boolean value, i.e. `true` or `false`.

If `anchor` is truthy (i.e. there's an object), then `Boolean(anchor)` returns `true`.

If `anchor` is falsy (e.g. it's `null`), then `Boolean(anchor)` returns `false`.

In your code snippet, it means that Menu prop `open` will be set to `true` if `anchor` is an object, and `false` if there's no object (if `anchor` is `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax open={Boolean(anchor)} refers to whether your Menu will open/close as the type of **open** props is Boolean.
And here **Boolean(anchor)** type converting is used to convert anchor value in to Boolean value.

So when you set **anchor** value as like event.target.value or ref based then
Boolean(anchor) === true
But when you reset the anchor value like null or undefined then
Boolean(anchor) === false

So based on that your Menu Element open/close